# Showing data from a Website

Tags: android, web-applications

i am fairly new at developing with Android but am trying to learn to learn new things:

I wanted to build a simple app that would take data from a website and then show it on the app. I considered using WebView but WebView seems to just put a browser within the app.

I understand that an app such as this would have to 1) Communicate a login and password and pass it to the website and then 2) show the data in the app

What i wanted to do was integrate the data into the app. Another question is if there are  any implications regarding this type of app because a user would have to log in using a Username and Password.

So how could I go about this(i just need some general pointers, what to use, etc.)

Thank You!

Comment: What sort of "data" do you want to show? HTML, images?

Comment: the Data would be HTML so just basic text. On the website itself it shows the data as charts, so i was thinking of using ListView but i dont know how to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTTPClient to execute a POST function to return the html data from a webpage. You would only have to provide login credentials if the page you're trying to access is username/password protected. A simple tutorial on this can be found here

http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/get-web-page-source-code-in-android/